# NodeJS eventLoop + ExpressJS unexpected behaviour with concurrency requests on single route

Tags: node.js, express, threadpool, pm2, event-loop

I have a simple express App with a single route:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const crypto = require("crypto");

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const start = new Date()
    console.log('Start timestamp', `${start.getTime()}`);
    crypto.pbkdf2('foo', 'bar', 800000, 512, 'sha512', () => {
       console.log('End diff ', new Date()- start)
       res.send('Success')
    })
})
app.listen(3000);
```

I'm run this app on localhost. **Single request time is equal near 3.2 seconds**.
I have Mac M1 with 8 CPU cores. Expected that when i get 4 concurrency requests on my App '/' route, they will be running through the 4хthreadPool's and split into 4 different/separated cores.

But when I'm send this 4 concurrency requests i have the next console.log:

```
Start timestamp 1653231979628
End diff  3256
Start timestamp 1653231982889
Start timestamp 1653231982889
Start timestamp 1653231982889
End diff  3437
End diff  3438
End diff  3439
```

So, firstly running one request, it freezing the event loop, and after it finished, other 3 requests will processed simultaneously.

What is the most interesting for me, is that when I'm running this app with pm2 as 4 separated Node-instances, this behaviour is the same. But how it can be, especially when running 4 different pm2-instances?

Comment: It looks to me like they're all generally running in parallel (all take 3.5 seconds to respond). What do you get if you make only 1 request? Around 3 seconds? If your theory is true then 1 request (instead of 4) should take around 0.7-0.9 seconds to respond. If my theory is true then 1 request should take around 2-3 seconds to respond.

Comment: @slebetman , yea one request duration is near 3.2 seconds. But If u look at "Start timestamps " you can see that first request start at ...79628 timestamp and 3 other one starts at ...82889 timestamp, so start time difference is 3.2 seconds between first request and 3 others

Comment: How are you making the requests? curl?

Comment: @slebetman apache benchmark. ab -c 4 -n 4 localhost:3000/

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is a single-threaded event loop. In your example, there are two types of event:

A. Incoming request

- The start timestamp is logged.
- The crypto operation is started.
- Wait for next event.

B. Crypto operation finished

- The callback function is invoked.

  - The end timestamp is logged.
  - The "Success" message is sent as a response.
- Wait for next event.

In your run with 4 requests, the event sequence was A1, B1, A2, A3, A4, B2, B3, B4. Whether the next event is A or B depends also on the speed with which the crypto operations are executed.

Comment: `If you run 4 separated Node.js instances, then they cannot all listen on the same port` this is not true. Running node using the cluster module (https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) allows multiple independent processes to share the same port. In such a case what happens is that the cluster listener will pass the pointer to the socket to a process in a load-balancing way (usually round-robin) and then let that process handle all IO to the socket. Therefore you essentially have 4 + 1 event loops (4 event loops handling requests + 1 load balancing event loop) that run completely independently

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I have removed the wrong statement from my answer.

Comment: Note that using `cluster` the server processes do not send the response back to the master process like Nginx/Apache load balancing. They independently handle all communications back to the client.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen but what about libuv threadPools, which should work with some nodeJs libraries, like "crypto" (which i used in my example) for redirect long-time crypto-functions into separated CPU cores and give some multithreading for crypto-functions? 

Single time for processing 1 request is 3.2 sec, and as we see - three last request's really run simultaneously, they starts at one timestamp and all finished after 3 seconds.

Comment: Rrquests 2, 3 and 4 came in while the crypto operation of A1 was executed, apparently on the same thread as Node.js. When that crypto operation was finished, event B1 was emitted, before events A2, A3 and A4.